# SWT Popup Composite unexpected disposal

Tags: java, swt

So I've [stolen this cool `PopupComposite`](http://palea.cgrb.oregonstate.edu/svn/jaiswallab/Annotation/src/ie/dcu/swt/PopupComposite.java), and I am really satisfied with it.

There's just one issue. If it put a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text` in it, I open the popup, focus the `Text`, and press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then both the `Text` and the `PopupComposite` dispose themselves.

I really can't figure out where the dispose call is coming from. Is it a `Shell` issue? What `Shell` should I use with the popup?

**SSCCE**:

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class PopupCompositeTester
{

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new PopupCompositeTester();
    }

    private PopupCompositeTester()
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        createContents(shell);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if ( !display.readAndDispatch() )
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void createContents(final Composite parent)
    {
        final Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Poke Me");

        final PopupComposite popup = new PopupComposite(parent.getShell());
        new Text(popup, SWT.NONE);
        popup.pack();

        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            @Override public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
                popup.show( Display.getDefault().map(parent, null, button.getLocation()) );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because when you focus the text field and press Escape, the field sends a `SWT.TRAVERSE_ESCAPE` event to its parent shell. The shell (in your case not being a top-level shell) responds by calling `Shell.close()`. You can work around that by adding a traverse listener to your text field, which would cancel the event (code below).

```
new Text(popup, SWT.NONE).addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
        if(e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_ESCAPE) {
            e.doit = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Keep in mind, this is a rather crude solution to your specific issue. I would not recommend using this for anything other than testing purposes. You can read more about this here -> http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FTraverseEvent.html

And here: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FShell.html

Answer (score 0):

Because my "bug" is actually a normal behaviour of the SWT platform, I've used the following workaround:

```
/**
 * Lazy initialization of the popup composite
 */
private void createPopup()
{
     // popupContainer is now a field
     if (popupContainer != null && !popupContainer.isDisposed())
         return;

     // ... create popup AND its contents ...
}
```

and in the button listener:

```
createPopup();
popup.show( Display.getDefault().map(parent, null, button.getLocation()) );
```

**Thank you [@blgt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2685386)**